Rails: No route matches [POST] "/admin/users/bulk_actions/delete"
I have developed the sign,sign_up and log_out using devise..  Here i am trying to select one or multiple checkbox to do following actions:block,unblock,delete..After blocking a user he/she can't login and hit status will be updated to block..if any of the user unblock him then he can login..Deleted user can register..
This is my view code:
 <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        User Management
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <%= form_tag(admin_users_path, method: :post, id: "bulk-actions-form") do %>
          <table class="table table-light table-hover table-striped">
            <thead class="table-dark">
              <tr>
                <th><input type="checkbox" id="select-all" onclick="toggleAllCheckboxes()"></th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Last Login Time</th>
                <th>Registration Time</th>
                <th>Status</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <% @users.each do |user| %>
                <tr>
                  <td><input type="checkbox" name="user_ids[]" value="<%= user.id %>"></td>
                  <td><%= user.id %></td>
                  <td><%= user.username %></td>
                  <td><%= user.email %></td>
                  <td><%= user.last_sign_in_at %></td>
                  <td><%= user.created_at %></td>
                  <td><%= user.status %></td>
                </tr>
              <% end %>
            </tbody>
          </table>
    
          <div class="button-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="bulkAction('block')">Block</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="bulkAction('unblock')">Unblock</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="bulkAction('delete')">Delete</button>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>
      // Function to handle bulk actions
      function bulkAction(action) {
        var form = document.getElementById("bulk-actions-form");
        var actionUrl;
    
        switch (action) {
          case 'block':
            actionUrl = "/admin/users/bulk_actions/block";
            break;
          case 'unblock':
            actionUrl = "/admin/users/bulk_actions/unblock";
            break;
          case 'delete':
            actionUrl = "/admin/users/bulk_actions/delete";
            break;
        }
    
        form.action = actionUrl;
        form.submit();
      }
    
      // Function to toggle all checkboxes based on the header checkbox
      function toggleAllCheckboxes() {
        var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='user_ids[]']");
        var selectAllCheckbox = document.getElementById("select-all");
    
        checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
          checkbox.checked = selectAllCheckbox.checked;
        });
    
        // Set indeterminate state if only some checkboxes are checked
        selectAllCheckbox.indeterminate = checkboxes.length > 0 && !Array.from(checkboxes).every(checkbox => checkbox.checked) && !Array.from(checkboxes).every(checkbox => !checkbox.checked);
      }
    </script>

Controller :
 class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController
      before_action :restrict_to_post_or_delete_request, only: [:bulk_actions, :block, :unblock, :bulk_delete]
      
      def index
        @users = User.all
      end
    
      def bulk_actions
        action = params[:action_type]
        case action
        when 'block'
          User.where(id: params[:user_ids]).update_all(status: 'blocked')
          redirect_to admin_users_path, notice: 'Users blocked successfully'
        when 'unblock'
          User.where(id: params[:user_ids]).update_all(status: 'active')
          redirect_to admin_users_path, notice: 'Users unblocked successfully'
        when 'delete'
          User.where(id: params[:user_ids]).destroy_all
          redirect_to admin_users_path, notice: 'Users deleted successfully'
        else
          redirect_to admin_users_path, alert: 'Invalid action'
        end
      end
    
      def block
        user = User.find(params[:id])
        user.update(status: 'blocked')
        redirect_to admin_users_path, notice: 'User blocked successfully'
      end
    
      def unblock
        user = User.find(params[:id])
        user.update(status: 'active')
        redirect_to admin_users_path, notice: 'User unblocked successfully'
      end
    
      def bulk_delete
        User.where(id: params[:user_ids]).destroy_all
        redirect_to admin_users_path, notice: 'Users deleted successfully'
      end
    
      private
    
      def restrict_to_post_or_delete_request
        unless request.post? || request.delete?
          redirect_to root_path, alert: 'Invalid request'
        end
      end
    end

Routes:
namespace :admin do

    resources :users do
      post :bulk_actions, on: :collection
      post :block, on: :member
      post :unblock, on: :member
      delete :bulk_actions, on: :collection  # Define delete route for bulk_actions
    end
  end


Based on your routes.rb, you've defined [DELETE] "/admin/users/bulk_actions", not [POST] "/admin/users/bulk_actions/delete"]. You can run rails routes |grep bulk_actions to see which routes were defined in your router

@AbM protip - use rails routes -c bulk_actions instead of piping the output into grep. That way you get the headers.
